# Three.js - How do I determine intersections between a Mesh and a Particle System?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

I have a particle system using sprites which is an Object3D similar to the "interactive / points" example from three.js and a basic sphere mesh which follows my cursor.

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=point#webgl_interactive_points

[image: mesh intersection]

What's the best way to determine when two of these objects intersect? I want to be able to push the particles with the sphere, but first I need an array of the points which are "inside the sphere". Thanks!

Comment: I know there's [isPointInPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) for 2d canvas. Not finding something similar for 3d, but just wanted to share.

Comment: Sphere has center and radius, you can check the condidtion if the distance from a point to the sphere's center is less than sphere's radius, then the point is inside the sphere.

Answer (score 1):

To know if a point is inside or outside the sphere, you can cast a ray from the point in a given direction. Then count the ray intesection with the sphere geometry's triangles. If the count is odd, the point is inside, else it's outside.

Some demo showing particles injection into a mesh is available here (same principle)  https://github.com/heroncendre/Volpar